# Is there a node.js identity provider solution?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml, claims-based-identity, saml-2.0

We are implementing Single Sign On for our applications and we are currently investigating the various Identity Provider vendors that are available. Is there a node.js Identity Provider solution out there?

A vendor that supports standards such as SAML and possible OpenID Connect in the future.

We have been looking at other vendors in the JVM & .net space such as:

1. WSO2.
2. Thinktecture Identity Server.

Now we are looking if something exists in the node.js space?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Auth0 is node.js based.